# cordova jquery html() goes really slow in windows store app

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, windows-store-apps

I'm developing a Cordova multi-platform app and I have a very long JavaScript string of HTML (approx. 80,000 characters) that I want to set to a DOM element. It runs fine on Android (2-3 seconds) but in a Windows Store app, it takes forever (1 minute). I'm using jQuery's .html() function. I also tried the native .innerHTML property which didn't help. I heard that there has been security problems with setting raw HTML in Windows Store apps, is that the culprit here? Please let me know how I can speed this up or give me a workaround. Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid you've misunderstood the concept. HTML is meant to build up elements, CSS is for layout and styling, JS provides the functionality to a page.

Comment: Misunderstood what concept? I'm taking an Ajax response from my web server, therefore it's a variable and I need to show it to the user. How else can I do that besides put it in the DOM?

Comment: Concept === pure speculation without the code, ofcourse. There's no mention of AJAX in your question either ...